# select element not executing onclick for option in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Here's my code:

```
<select style="color:#000000">
<option onclick="window.location.href='/state/FL/1/city/asc'">Sort by City ASC</option>
<option onclick="window.location.href='/state/FL/1/city/desc'">Sort by City DESC</option>
<option onclick="window.location.href='/state/FL/1/name/asc'">Sort by Name ASC</option>
<option onclick="window.location.href='/state/FL/1/name/desc'">Sort by Name DESC</option>
<option onclick="window.location.href='/state/FL/1/dist/asc'">Sort by Distance Nearest</option>
<option onclick="window.location.href='/state/FL/1/dist/desc'">Sort by Distance Furthest</option>
```

You cannot see the end select tag but its there. It's not changing the page when I click an option `using chrome but it works for firefox`.

Not quite sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Onclick events on options are very inconsistent, so you should set an event on `change`, which in contrary, is supported in browsers. Also, inline javascript should be avoided - so give your select an `id` and do the following:

```
<select id="selectId" style="color:#000000">
<option value="/state/FL/1/city/asc">Sort by City ASC</option>
<option value="/state/FL/1/city/desc">Sort by City DESC</option>
<option value="/state/FL/1/name/asc">Sort by Name ASC</option>
<option value="/state/FL/1/name/desc">Sort by Name DESC</option>
<option value="/state/FL/1/dist/asc">Sort by Distance Nearest</option>
<option value="/state/FL/1/dist/desc">Sort by Distance Furthest</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('selectID').addEventListener('change', e => {
    window.location.href = e.target.value;
});
```

Comment: Great Solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Options don't have mouse events in some browsers, which is why you should ***never*** use `onclick` handlers on options, but rather `onchange` handlers on the select.

With a proper event handler it would be

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option value="/state/FL/1/city/asc">Sort by City ASC</option>
    <option value="/state/FL/1/city/desc">Sort by City DESC</option>
    <option value="/state/FL/1/name/asc">Sort by Name ASC</option>
    <option value="/state/FL/1/name/desc">Sort by Name DESC</option>
    <option value="/state/FL/1/dist/asc">Sort by Distance Nearest</option>
    <option value="/state/FL/1/dist/desc">Sort by Distance Furthest</option>
</select>
```

and then in a script tag

```
document.getElementById('mySelect').addEventListener('change', function() {

    window.location.href = this.value;

}, false):
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery example:

```js
$('#select').change(function(){
  var currentHref = $(this).find('option:selected').data('href');
  window.location.href = currentHref;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select" style="color:#000000">
<option data-href="/state/FL/1/city/asc">Sort by City ASC</option>
<option data-href="/state/FL/1/city/desc">Sort by City DESC</option>
<option data-href="/state/FL/1/name/asc">Sort by Name ASC</option>
<option data-href="/state/FL/1/name/desc">Sort by Name DESC</option>
<option data-href="/state/FL/1/dist/asc">Sort by Distance Nearest</option>
<option data-href="/state/FL/1/dist/desc">Sort by Distance Furthest</option>
</select>
```